# Slick Carousel Angular - dynamic data loading

Tags: javascript, angularjs, carousel, slick.js

When I use dynamic data to load the slick content, all the images come one below the other. I do not know why it happens. How do I resolve it? Looks like DOM needs data at initialization itself.

View:

```html
<slick infinite=true slides-to-show=3 slides-to-scroll=3 settings="slickConfig" data="images">
    <div class="slick-item" ng-repeat="image in images">
        <div class="Slide-Id">
            <p class="slide-id">{{images.indexOf(image)+1}}/{{images.length}}</p>
        </div>
        <img src="{{image.url}}" height="100px" width="100px" />
    </div>
</slick>
```

```css
// $scope.images = [ {
      //     url: '../../images/qr-code.png'
      //   }, {
      //     url: '../../images/qr-code.png'
      //   }, {
      //     url: '../../images/qr-code.png'
      //   }, {
      //     url: '../../images/qr-code.png'
      //   }, {
      //     url: '../../images/qr-code.png'
      //   }];
   
   //Hard coded values above loads properly as expected. But if it comes from server and then,
   //it loads one below the other.
   
   
   $scope.images = [];

        $scope.slickConfig = {
        //enabled: true,
        //autoplay: false,
        //draggable: true,  
       // method: {},
        arrows: false,
        //centerMode:true,
        //variableWidth: true,
        event: {
            beforeChange: function (event, slick, currentSlide, nextSlide) {
            },
            afterChange: function (event, slick, currentSlide, nextSlide) {
            }
        }
      };
   
   ...
    var data = ServiceFactory.getEventDetails();
    data
                 .then(onAuthenticated )
                 .catch(onRejectedRequest)
                 .finally(sessionServiceFinally);
     
     ....
     
     onAuthenticated(resp){
      console.log("vm.tickets[i].images.." + resp[0].images);
       $scope.images.push({url : resp[0].images});
       $scope.images.push({url : resp[0].images});
       $scope.images.push({url : resp[0].images});
     
     }
```

Answer (score 0):

I finally ended up using ng-if for this one to resolve :)